# $GPGLL (Geographic position, latitude / longitude ) information to a visual map

Tags: gps

I recorded my gps output(only GPGLL sentences) in a some database, and now I need to add an ability to see in some kind of a map or an actual picture according to this databasr information.
( I mean: given a geographic position,Latitude and Longitude and I want to get a picture like google earth give).

is there some kind of a service that provides it to you?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to do some conversions but google maps has a api that will display the location on the map. With some reading and learning of the api, you will also be able to show the path of a recorded series of locations.